# Why sound settings in GNOME Control Center is recognising Google Chrome as Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, 20.04, gnome-control-center

I have installed Google Chrome in Ubuntu 20.04. Whenever I play sound in Chrome, sound settings show the volume control settings for Chromium even when I don't have Chromium installed.

[image]

Why is GNOME Control Center recognising Google Chrome as Chromium?

Comment: It's simply because the developers didn't care which Chromium based browser is running. You can report it as a bug, if it is so important to you.

Comment: Same thing on Kubuntu 18.04! Although they get the Chrome icon correct. I'll check in Kubuntu 20.04 as well.

Comment: @DKBose I'm making a guess here. The settings app relies on Pulseaudio to know which app is using the sound and pulseaudio is detecting the application as Chromium.

Comment: Same thing on Kubuntu 20.04. The icon is correct but the name is Chromium. I wonder what some other browsers such as Brave or Vivaldi or Opera register as. I'll check with Falkon.

Comment: Falkon, on Kubuntu 18.04, is seen as Falkon. So not all webkit browsers are lumped together as Chromium.

Comment: @DKBose I tried Brave. Although it is seen as Brave but the icon is of Chromium/Chrome.

Comment: In black/white there's not much different between the Chrome/Chromium icons. Kubuntu shows them in color. So the diff is clear. Falkon appears with its own icon.

Comment: **Voting to close:** The GNOME settings no longer shows Google Chrome as Chromium. For reference see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgqC7.png).

Comment: @DKBose Can you please confirm if the issue still persists on Kubuntu 18.04?

Comment: it seems fixed in 22.04. Chrome still identifies as `chromium` in the mpris sound sources though